# Why the Retrofit response gives null value for fields, while the response can get the object?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm just making a simple application in Android Studio 2.3 to get a JSON response from the Web app. I chose Retrofit 2.0 for consuming the response.

---

It seems I could get the   objects inside `onResponse`

```
Object item =  response.body().get(1);
Log.e("success", String.valueOf(item));
```

inside logcat it gives a success,

```
success:com.makemyapp.firstapplication.Item@67205ae
```

But when tried to fetch the fields inside the object,

```
Object item =  response.body().get(1).getItemDescription();
Log.e("success", String.valueOf(item));
```

It returns a null

```
success: null
```

---

This is the Interface- **GrocsApi**,

```
package com.makemyapp.firstapplication;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface GrocsApi {

    @GET("api/getitemlist")
    Call<List<Item>> getItem();

}
```

Class for returning service- **GrocsService**

```
package com.makemyapp.firstapplication;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class GrocsService {

    public  static GrocsApi service;
    public static String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/";


    public static GrocsApi getGrocsService(){
        if (service==null){

            Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                              .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                              .build();
            service = retrofit.create(GrocsApi.class);

            return service;
        }

return  service;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java** ,where Request Call is initiated,

```
package com.makemyapp.firstapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button;
    //TextView textView; for later use


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onClickGetData();
    }


    public void onClickGetData(){

      //  textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); for later use
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
  Call<List<Item>> call =   GrocsService.getGrocsService().getItem();

           call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Item>>  () {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(Call<List<Item>>  call, Response<List<Item>>   response) {

 if(response.isSuccessful()) {
     Object item =  response.body().get(1).getItemDescription();

     Log.e("success", String.valueOf(item));

 } else{
     Log.e("response is not good", "");
 }
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(Call<List<Item>>   call, Throwable t) {

                      Log.e("failed", t.getMessage());

                  }
              });


            }

        }
    );
}
}
```

This is my POJO class- **Item**

```
package com.makemyapp.firstapplication;


public class Item {

    private Integer itemId;
    private Object itemName;
    private Object itemDescription;
    private Object itemPhotoUrl;
    private Object itemWikipediaLink;
    private Object itemTag;

    public Integer getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(Integer itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public Object getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(Object itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public Object getItemDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }

    public void setItemDescription(Object itemDescription) {
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    }

    public Object getItemPhotoUrl() {
        return itemPhotoUrl;
    }

    public void setItemPhotoUrl(Object itemPhotoUrl) {
        this.itemPhotoUrl = itemPhotoUrl;
    }

    public Object getItemWikipediaLink() {
        return itemWikipediaLink;
    }

    public void setItemWikipediaLink(Object itemWikipediaLink) {
        this.itemWikipediaLink = itemWikipediaLink;
    }

    public Object getItemTag() {
        return itemTag;
    }

    public void setItemTag(Object itemTag) {
        this.itemTag = itemTag;
    }

}
```

And the JSON response is ,

```
[{"ItemId":1,"ItemName":"Orange","ItemDescription":"Sweet and Juicy","ItemPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Orange_(fruit)","ItemWikipediaLink":"'https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Orange_(fruit)#\/media\/File:Orange-Whole-%26-Split.jpg","ItemTag":"RS.70 per kg"},{"ItemId":3,"ItemName":"Apple","ItemDescription":"Reddish","ItemPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Apple","ItemWikipediaLink":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Apple#\/media\/File:Red_Apple.jpg","ItemTag":"RS.10 per kg"},{"ItemId":4,"ItemName":"Mango","ItemDescription":"Fresh","ItemPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Mango#\/media\/File:Mangoes_pic.jpg","ItemWikipediaLink":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Mango","ItemTag":"RS.100 per kg"},{"ItemId":5,"ItemName":"Pineapple","ItemDescription":"Large and Juicy","ItemPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Pineapple#\/media\/File:Pineapple_and_cross_section.jpg","ItemWikipediaLink":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Pineapple","ItemTag":"RS.50 per kg"},{"ItemId":6,"ItemName":"Grapes","ItemDescription":"Dark and Juicy","ItemPhotoUrl":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Grape#\/media\/File:Abhar-iran.JPG","ItemWikipediaLink":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Grape","ItemTag":"110 per kg"},{"ItemId":7,"ItemName":"Guava","ItemDescription":"Green","ItemPhotoUrl":null,"ItemWikipediaLink":null,"ItemTag":"50 per kg"},{"ItemId":8,"ItemName":null,"ItemDescription":null,"ItemPhotoUrl":null,"ItemWikipediaLink":null,"ItemTag":null}]
```

Could any one spot a light on my problem?

Comment: you miss @SerializedName on fields of your model.

Comment: please add com.makemyapp.firstapplication.Item class code, maybe it's simple serialization error

Comment: Specify exact types for fields in Item (String in your case) and add @SerializedName("ItemDescription") annotation to the field declaration

Comment: @Fakher and @ Viktor Yakunin I'm using the same variable name as in the Json. So, is it necessary to serialize?

Comment: the easy way to create POJO classes : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: I think naming is case sensitive and hence the variable name is not the same.

Comment: Oh! I haven't noticed it....You all are right! I was also created the pojo class using jsonschema2pojo.org. But I did not used the Gson annotation style.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `@SerializedName` on each field of Item class with the `JsonObject` name that will fill this field.

for example:

```
@SerializedName("ItemId") // Case sensitive
private Integer itemId;
```

In your `MainActivity`:

```
Call<List<Item>> call =   GrocsService.getGrocsService().getItem(); //It's here where you call getItem(). you will enque the request after that as you already did.
```

than in your `onResponse` callback, you get your list:

```
List<item> myResponse =  (List<Item>) response.body();
```

and than you fetch your list of items.

Comment: And Can you help me to get the contents of each variable in each object inside a single textView ?

Comment: if your response is just an Object (not a list) you can easily do that:
`Item item =  response.body();
yourTextView.setText(item.getItemName);`

Comment: My response is a List of objects!

Comment: Also I have a doubt. Actually where goes the definition of  Call<List<Item>>getItem();  | Is it inside an anonymous class?

Comment: I understand that and in your updated answer, I think it is not necessary to cast the response.body() to a List. Because response.body() is already a List of Items.

Comment: but my doubt is that , why don't we implement the method in the Interface somewhere else?

Comment: No it's retrofit that implement it. Youjust give the end point, the method and your parameters if you have

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is : "itemDescription" but your json response is 'ItemDescription" , you should consider that the parser is case-sensitive.